# Android build errors (porting to ICS)

Tags: android, build

I am working on porting from gb to ics in android

I have changed path of a particular folder and kept it at a different path 
after build I get many errors stating that the files doesn't exist because those files are present in that folder which I have copied in a different path

How can I link my build and code to pick up my new path because in my Java files I just write `import com.android`, and not the actual entire path of the file.

How and where to mention the entire path of the folder?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not clear what the problem is, and has been abandoned by the OP.

Comment: In that case you should probably flag for *unclear what you're asking*

Answer (score 1):

Right click your project. Select Build Path -> Configure build path -> Java build path

Here you can specify the path of changed library.

Comment: no actually we have a .mk file where we make entry of all the paths and im not making an app im integrating one app to another without using eclipse ..